# Class or Function in PHP for generateing printable receipts

Tags: php, epson

I have a ticket printer (EPSON TM-U220) and I am working on a billing system in PHP and MySQL, My question is, If anyone knows of any classes or functions written in PHP to Build the Ticket or Invoice with the correct format for this type of printer?

Comment: Couldn't you just find out how many characters wide the tickets should be and then format the text outputted from PHP accordingly?

Comment: I only need to know the name of a script that generates an invoice ticket type, written in php. Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to send a document to the printer or do you want to communicate with the driver directly?

Comment: What is an "invoice ticket type"? Wouldn't the invoice/ticket be specific for your application's data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to produce a document to send to the printer, I think you should not bother with formats and just create a PDF. There are a lot of libraries to create pdf from xhtml/html.

If you want to communicate with the printer itself, you will need to start with the [tech ressources](http://pos.epson.com/developers/techresdetails.htm?productpk=545) of the respective printer.

Comment: Very, Very nice idea!, Your answer help me a lot!